# Continuous JavaScript execution until the person leaves the page?

Tags: javascript, mobile, geolocation

I want to create a browser-based application that continuously polls the users' current GPS location using HTML5's `geolocation` feature. Most of the users being tracked will be on mobile devices.

I understand I can get users' location through the following code:

```
<script>
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
  console.log(location.coords.latitude);
  console.log(location.coords.longitude);
  console.log(location.coords.accuracy);
});
</script>
```

However, I am unsure how I can execute this JavaScript code continuously. I want the JavaScript code to execute, even if the screen is locked and the phone is on "wait" mode.

My questions are:

- Is this achievable through browser-based technology?
- Am I using the wrong tool for the job? Should I be looking into building native mobile apps?

Comment: You might look into using `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't guarantee that your JavaScript code will continue to run after the user has left the tab or put the device to sleep. The web client reserves the right to hibernate your code in circumstances like this, and there's nothing you can do to force it to keep your code running.

I'd look into alternatives like building a mobile app version.